# File Not Found Error for load and read a JSON file in jupyter notebook Watson IBM Studio

Tags: python, json, ibm-watson

I am working on IBM cloud Watson Studion environment. I wrote this script to get the updated population per municipality in Norway. The JSON file is uploaded in the assets of my project and I am trying to call and read it with the `"with open"` but I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Folkemengde.json'
```

I used also but the result still the same:

```
pd.read_json ('Folkemengde.json')
```

How can I get the path of the JSON file when it is already uploaded in the assets? Or does it work like this with JSON files or does not matter?

My script

```
population_data = {}
with open("Folkemengde.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as inp:
        data = json.load(inp)
        kommuns_index = data["dataset"]["dimension"]["Region"]["category"]["index"]
        kommuns_label = data["dataset"]["dimension"]["Region"]["category"]["label"]
        values = data["dataset"]["value"]
        for i, municipality_code_str in enumerate(kommuns_index.keys()):
            k = municipality_code_str[2:]
            if k == "Rest":
                continue
            municipality_name = kommuns_label[municipality_code_str]
            population = values[i]
            population_data[int(k)] = population
            
    def from_municipality_pop(row):
        global population_data
        if row['from_municipality_code'] == 0:
            return 0
        return population_data[row['from_municipality_code']]
    df['population'] = df.apply(lambda row: from_municipality_pop(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with help from https://medium.com/@snehalgawas/working-with-ibm-cloud-object-storage-in-python-fe0ba8667d5f:

To access IBM Cloud Object Storage you need credentials which you insert by opening the notebook and click to `Find and Add Data`, click on `insert credentials`.
It will give something that looks like this:

```
# @hidden_cell
# The following code contains the credentials for a file in your IBM Cloud Object Storage.
# You might want to remove those credentials before you share your notebook.
credentials = {
    'IBM_API_KEY_ID': '*******************************',
    'IAM_SERVICE_ID': '*******************************',
    'ENDPOINT': '*******************************',
    'IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT': '*******************************',
    'BUCKET': '*******************************',
    'FILE': '*******************************'
}
```

Then with those credentials create a low-level client like:

```
from ibm_botocore.client import Config
import ibm_boto3
cos = ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',
    ibm_api_key_id=credentials['IBM_API_KEY_ID'],
    ibm_service_instance_id=credentials['IAM_SERVICE_ID'],
    ibm_auth_endpoint=credentials['IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT'],
    config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
    endpoint_url=credentials['ENDPOINT'])
```

Then get that file as an object with the client credentials:
Get the file as object and load the data:

```
any_name = cos.get_object(Bucket= credentials['BUCKET'], Key='Your_file_name.json')['Body']
data = json.load(any_name)
```